# How to encrypt the data at rest in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: encryption, activemq-artemis

I want to encrypt the data at rest in ActiveMQ Artemis. Could not find a resource suggesting the expected configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis does not support data encryption at rest. You should either encrypt your data end-to-end or use file-system based encryption.